# Gradle mixing versions 27.1.1 and 26.1.0 [Android Studio]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For the build.gradle configuration, everything is ok.

```
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

dependencies {
implementation project(':market_licensing')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
}
```

When I migrate to version 27,

```
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

dependencies {
implementation project(':market_licensing')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
}
```

**I have an error:**

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0.

Why am I still showing a conflict with the old version 26.1.0? I do clean.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification

Comment: I have removed the implementation project (': market_licensing')
   The error is still.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`customtabs` need to be provided in version `27.1.1` ...

```
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1"
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "customtabs"
}
```

Comment: The error has been removed. Your tips helped.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and rebuild your project. Also if it does not work check whether all dependencies are the same and maybe change versions to a bit newer or older ones.

I also strongly recommend using androidX it's  feels really good to me